# Element Tree's iter() is skipping over random elements

Tags: python, xml, parsing, text, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an XML file using Element Tree's iterparse() and iter() functions in Python. Here is a link to the file in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_S2Z7quow3TMl9yUk51ZzZ5UW8/view?usp=sharing.

The XML file is a compilation of data on court cases; it is broken up into a series of elements with tag "n-document," each of which contains sub-elements that contain data on a particular court case. I'm trying to extract all of the docket descriptions. A simplified version of the code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import re
import csv

for event, elem in etree.iterparse("***fileName***", events=("start", "end")):
    if event == "start":
        if elem.tag == "docket.entry":
            for element in elem.iter():
                print element.tag
                if element.text != None:
                    print element.text
                if element.tail != None:
                    print element.tail
                    print "from tail"
    elem.clear()
```

The problem is that in the first case (1613 HARVARD LIMITED PARTNERSHIP V. DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA ET AL), the docket description numbered 25 (they're numbered in descending order) is missing the text and tail of the element with tag "gateway.image.link". Specifically, here's the output that I get. I just canceled the build after a second and scrolled up to the very top of the console:

```
docket.entry
number.block
number
28
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
07/19/2007
docket.description
ORDER GRANTING DEFENDANTS' MOTION TO DISMISS AND DENYING PLAINTIFF'S MOTION FOR LEAVE TO FILE A SECOND AMENDED COMPLAINT. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 7/19/07. (LCRWR1, ) (ENTERED: 07/19/2007)
docket.entry
number.block
number
27
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
07/19/2007
docket.description
MEMORANDUM OPINION. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 7/19/07. (LCRWR1) MODIFIED ON 7/19/2007 (LCRWR1, ). (ENTERED: 07/19/2007)
docket.entry
number.block
number
26
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
03/31/2007
docket.description
MEMORANDUM ORDER GRANTING DEFENDANTS' MOTION
image.gateway.link
21
gateway.image.link
21
 TO STAY DISCOVERY PENDING RESOLUTION OF DEFENDANTS' DISPOSITIVE MOTION FILED BY PATRICK J. CANAVAN, PAUL E. WATERS. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 3/31/07. (LCRWR1) ADDITIONAL ATTACHMENT(S) ADDED ON 4/3/2007 (LCRWR1, ). (ENTERED: 04/02/2007)
from tail
docket.entry
number.block
number
25
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
11/15/2005
docket.description
RESPONSE TO DEFENDANTS' NOTICE OF COURT RULING IN RELATED CASE FILED BY 1613 HARVARD LIMITED PARTNERSHIP. (ATTACHMENTS: #
image.gateway.link
docket.entry
number.block
number
24
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
11/14/2005
docket.description
NOTIFICATION OF SUPPLEMENTAL AUTHORITY BY DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA, PATRICK J. CANAVAN, PAUL E. WATERS (ATTACHMENTS: #
image.gateway.link
1
gateway.image.link
1
)(MULLEN, MARTHA) (ENTERED: 11/14/2005)
from tail
```

Under entry number 25 (the second from the bottom of the output shown above), it says:

```
25
image.block
image.gateway.link
gateway.image.link
date
11/15/2005
docket.description
RESPONSE TO DEFENDANTS' NOTICE OF COURT RULING IN RELATED CASE FILED BY 1613 HARVARD LIMITED PARTNERSHIP. (ATTACHMENTS: #
image.gateway.link
```

The problem is that if you look the XML file itself, you'll see that there is also an element with tag "gateway.image.link" that immediately follows "image.gateway.link" with text and tail content, but for some reason the iter() function doesn't pick it up. What's strange is that most of the other docket descriptions also have elements with tag "image.gateway.link" immediately followed by an element with tag "gateway.image.link," as you can see from entry number 24 (and the rest of them), and the iter() function recognizes those but not this one. Here's excerpted XML code from the Google Drive document I pasted a link to above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><n-extract-response>
<docket.entries.block><label>Entry #:</label><label>Date:</label><label>Description:</label><docket.entry><number.block><number>28</number><image.block><image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.ID="godls|0450912204;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" item.type="main" platform="ecf"></image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="A1-280450912204" casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="main" key="godls|0450912204;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ecf"></gateway.image.link></image.block></number.block><date>07/19/2007</date><docket.description>ORDER GRANTING DEFENDANTS&apos; MOTION TO DISMISS AND DENYING PLAINTIFF&apos;S MOTION FOR LEAVE TO FILE A SECOND AMENDED COMPLAINT. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 7/19/07. (LCRWR1, ) (ENTERED: 07/19/2007)</docket.description></docket.entry><docket.entry><number.block><number>27</number><image.block><image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.ID="godls|04501909813;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" item.type="main" platform="ecf"></image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="A2-2704501909813" casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="main" key="godls|04501909813;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ecf"></gateway.image.link></image.block></number.block><date>07/19/2007</date><docket.description>MEMORANDUM OPINION. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 7/19/07. (LCRWR1) MODIFIED ON 7/19/2007 (LCRWR1, ). (ENTERED: 07/19/2007)</docket.description></docket.entry><docket.entry><number.block><number>26</number><image.block><image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.ID="godls|04501672579;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" item.type="main" platform="ecf"></image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="A4-2604501672579" casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="main" key="godls|04501672579;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ecf"></gateway.image.link></image.block></number.block><date>03/31/2007</date><docket.description>MEMORANDUM ORDER GRANTING DEFENDANTS&apos; MOTION<image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.id="godls|0450561212;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" item.type="ATTACHMENT" platform="ECF">21</image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="B3-21-0450561212" casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="ATTACHMENT" key="godls|0450561212;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ECF">21</gateway.image.link> TO STAY DISCOVERY PENDING RESOLUTION OF DEFENDANTS&apos; DISPOSITIVE MOTION FILED BY PATRICK J. CANAVAN, PAUL E. WATERS. SIGNED BY JUDGE RICHARD W. ROBERTS ON 3/31/07. (LCRWR1) ADDITIONAL ATTACHMENT(S) ADDED ON 4/3/2007 (LCRWR1, ). (ENTERED: 04/02/2007)</docket.description></docket.entry><docket.entry><number.block><number>25</number><image.block><image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.ID="godls|04501577842;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" item.type="main" platform="ecf"></image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="A6-2504501577842" casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="main" key="godls|04501577842;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ecf"></gateway.image.link></image.block></number.block><date>11/15/2005</date><docket.description>RESPONSE TO DEFENDANTS&apos; NOTICE OF COURT RULING IN RELATED CASE FILED BY 1613 HARVARD LIMITED PARTNERSHIP. (ATTACHMENTS: #<image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.id="godls|04511581037;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" item.type="ATTACHMENT" platform="ECF">1</image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="B5-1-04511581037" casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="ATTACHMENT" key="godls|04511581037;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ECF">1</gateway.image.link> EXHIBIT 1 - NOTICE OF APPEAL)(WISE, RICHARD) (ENTERED: 11/15/2005)</docket.description></docket.entry><docket.entry><number.block><number>24</number><image.block><image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.ID="godls|04501579104;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" item.type="main" platform="ecf"></image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="A8-2404501579104" casenumber="1:05cv00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="main" key="godls|04501579104;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05cv00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ecf"></gateway.image.link></image.block></number.block><date>11/14/2005</date><docket.description>NOTIFICATION OF SUPPLEMENTAL AUTHORITY BY DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA, PATRICK J. CANAVAN, PAUL E. WATERS (ATTACHMENTS: #<image.gateway.link casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" image.id="godls|04511577643;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" item.type="ATTACHMENT" platform="ECF">1</image.gateway.link><gateway.image.link ID="B7-1-04511577643" casenumber="1:05CV00726" court="DCDCT-DW" item.type="ATTACHMENT" key="godls|04511577643;court=DCDCT-DW;casenumber=1:05CV00726" tlr-class="gateway-image-link" ttype="ECF">1</gateway.image.link>)(MULLEN, MARTHA) (ENTERED: 11/14/2005)</docket.description></docket.entry></docket.entries.block>
</n-extract-response>
```

When I run my Python script on this particular excerpt exactly as pasted above, it gets the missing element. But when I run the script on the entire XML file, it doesn't, as shown earlier. Obviously, the excerpt is missing a lot of elements above and below it, but I don't see how that would affect the iter() function since I didn't break apart a "docket.entry" element/sub-elements, and that's what the for loop in my code is supposed to go through each time (I think).

The problem isn't limited to entry number 25--there are a few other extracted docket descriptions here and there that are missing a sub-element, but I can't discern any pattern--I can't even tell the difference between entry number 25 and entry number 24 that's causing the issue. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant part of xml in this question?

Comment: mata figured out what I was doing wrong. Thanks for offering to take a look at it, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to process an elements' children on a start-event, but the way `iterparse` works, it doesn't guarantee that they have already been read.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) has a note about this:

> **Note:**
>
> iterparse() only guarantees that it has seen the “>” character of a starting tag when it emits a “start” event, so the attributes are defined, but the contents of the text and tail attributes are undefined at that point. The same applies to the element children; they may or may not be present.
>
> If you need a fully populated element, look for “end” events instead.

If you want to process an elements children, you need to do it on the end-event, otherwise there is no guarantee for what content of the element will be available.

The reason why you get any content at all is described [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm):

> **Note:**
>
> The tree builder and the event generator are not necessarily synchronized; the latter usually lags behind a bit. This means that when you get a “start” event for an element, the builder may already have filled that element with content. You cannot rely on this, though — a “start” event can only be used to inspect the attributes, not the element content. For more details, see [this message](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2005-January/010838.html).

Comment: Doesn't the iter() function process end events, though? Also, when I change "if event == "start" to "if event == end" in the code above, the output is just "docket.entry" over and over with an occasional "date" and "docket.description" tag output--is that because if it has already reached the end tag for "docket.entry," it doesn't have any sub-elements to iterate over?

Comment: That's probably because you're unconditionally calling `elem.clear()`, for all elements. You only should do that after you don't need the element and its content anymore, otherwise you're clearing the children before reaching the end event. `iter()` does not generate or consume events, it iterates the element tree that has been constructed in memory until this point.

Answer (score 0):

getchildren is deprecated since version 2.7: Use list(elem) or iteration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10425523)

Comment: I have not enough "reputation" to comment Kaneg post.
Thats why I add an answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can choose to parse the xml file according to it's logical order, so you can accurately control every element. E.g.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'<xml file name>')
root = tree.getroot()
docket_entries = root.findall('.//docket.entry')
for entry in docket_entries:
    number = entry.find('.//number')
    print number.text
    description = entry.find('docket.description')
    print description.text
    for child in description.getchildren():
        print child
```

Comment: `iterparse` is used to iteratively parse large xml documents _without_ having to keep the whole tree in memory as your solution would need to do.